Trying to import csv from gmail into google sheets
I am new to google app scripts and am having trouble with getting my script to work.
Each morning I am sent csv's from various different partners with end of campaign data on. The aim is for the script to run from the spreadsheet on a time trigger to go find the email in my gmail, parse the csv data and paste it at the last row of the same sheet. I have managed (with the help of another) to get a script that does this perfectly well but when I try to use the same script in another sheet, changing the subject and sheet to import into it doesn't work. The script executes and completes without error but the data doesn't appear. When the same script is run by another user it imports.
I can see the email that it is supposed to find in my inbox but no joy. Any thoughts would be muchly appreciated.
I have double checked the script against one that works
function ExtractCSVFromGmailAndImport() {
// Start of Task
  var subject = "Brand metric JPI report";
 var sheet =
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Ended Campaigns');
// Get the Gmail label
 var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:' + subject + '"',0,1);
 if (threads.length > 0) {
var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
if (messages.length > 0) {
  var message = messages[0];
  var attachments = message.getAttachments();
  for (var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
    var attachment = attachments[i];
    if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString()).slice(1);  // Removes CSV Headers
     Logger.log("Email Contents: " + csvData)
     Logger.log("Last Row: " + sheet.getLastRow() + 1)
     sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
    }
  }
} else {
  Logger.log("No emails found with the specified subject this morning.");
}
 } else {
Logger.log("No emails found with the specified subject this morning.");
}
 // End of task
}


Hi there :) it's difficult to troubleshoot without the script!

I have added the code now, I was struggling to get it to paste in
